# Get the value of 'specific Times' array (IIS) from powershell

Tags: powershell, iis, iis-7

I am trying to retrieve the specific times values from IIS.
But I get back some sort of reference to a configuration element.

This is for a Microsoft Internet Information Services (version 10.0.14393.0).

I tried

```
$itemsInIis = Get-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool -Name recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.collection
Write-Host "Times present in IIS: [$itemsInIis]."
```

I get back 
`Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement`
instead of the actual values. How Should I do this to retrieve the times such as 00:00:00

NOt sure what I am missing here to retrieve the actual times inside the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting back an array of ConfigurationElements, each of which has `value` of type `TimeSpan`. Try something like this:

```
$itemsInIis = (Get-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool -Name recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.collection).value -F 'hhmmsss'
Write-Host "Times present in IIS: [$itemsInIis]."
```

Comment: You may want to use `HH` rather than `hh` here to specify the 24-hour clock rather than the 12-hour one.